# how to call parent class method in php

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, scope-resolution

This is the working code, but i want to know without using another object(commented `$foo`) how could i use `printItem()` method of `class Foo` using the `$bar` object. New to oop programming concept so may be a weak thing to ask but really unable to locate :(

I use scope resolution operator to use `printItem()` of `Foo class`, now my query is when we can use this functionality then what is the use of creating objects ? When to use scope resolution operators in proper coding environment.

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public function printItem($string)
    {
        echo "This is in class Foo ". $string ."<br />";
    }

    public function printPHP()
    {
        echo "PHP is great "."<br />";
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function printItem($string)
    {
        echo "This is in class Bar ". $string ."<br />";
    }
}       

//$foo = new Foo;
$bar = new Bar;

$bar->printPHP();
$bar->printItem("Bar class object");
//Foo::printItem("Mental Case");
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

define `printItem` as static method and you can use `Foo::printItem("Mental Case");`
or call it in child method:

```
public function printItem($string)
{
    parent::printItem($string);
    echo "This is in class Bar ". $string ."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
class test {

    public function __construct() {}

    public function name() {
       // $this->xname('John');
          $this->showName('John');
    }

    private function showName($name) {
        echo 'my name in test is '.$name;
    }
}

class extendTest extends test {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    private function showName($name) {
        echo 'my name in extendTest is '.$name;
    }
}

$test = new extendTest();
$test->name();
?>
```

result: my name in test is John

If we change visibility of the showName method to public or protected then the result of the above will be:
my name in extendTest is John

Comment: where is xname() defined and why did it print "my name is test john?"

Comment: i guess it was a typo by the answerer, corrected it

Answer (score 0):

Make printItem a static method by adding "static" keyword.
printItem($string) will be available to use without creating an object of this class.

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    static public function printItem($string)
    {
        echo "This is in class Foo ". $string ."<br />";
    }

    public function printPHP()
    {
        echo "PHP is great "."<br />";
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function printItem($string)
    {
        echo "This is in class Bar ". $string ."<br />";
    }
}       

//$foo = new Foo;
$bar = new Bar;

$bar->printPHP();
$bar->printItem("Bar class object");
//Foo::printItem("Mental Case");
```

Comment: I ran this code and found the error - FATAL ERROR Cannot make static method Foo::printItem() non static in class Bar on line number 22